# Switching between sessions in tmux using "C-b s" results in blank screen

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790061/switch-between-sessions-in-tmux) from whence I copied the image... except that

If I hit `C-b s` from within sessions `(0)`-`(6)` everything works fine.
However, if I hit `C-b s` when I'm in session `(7)` (not pictured) or above I get a blank screen.  If I then repeatedly hit `j` scrolling down until I eventually get to the `(0)` session then all the sessions display properly.  What else is weird about this is that if I type `:choose-session` instead of `C-b s` (per [this page](http://hyperpolyglot.org/multiplexers)) from the problem sessions >=`(7)`, then it works properly.

Any idea why this is happening and how I might fix it?

**UPDATE 2016-10-21 19:11:00Z**: I'm using tmuxinator w/ byobu mode if that might complicate things a bit.

[image]

Comment: Try with an empty tmux.conf file to see if it is possibly something you've put in there. Otherwise your best bet is to open an issue in the tmux github project: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues

Comment: Can you post your tmux.conf or (better) a reduced version of it with which that issue happens?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not because of the session itself? I mean: If you sort them to move it up, starts to work and moved down sessions begin to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `C-b s` calls `choose-tree` with params not `choose-session`. And there may be some problem with template that it uses in this command.

Try rebinding `s` directly to `choose-session` in your tmux.conf

```
bind s choose-session
```

Comment: @andersonbd1 you are welcome. I would steel consider reporting this to tmux team in their official repo