# Switch between sessions in tmux by name?

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I have similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790061/switch-between-sessions-in-tmux), but I wonder is there are an possibility to filter sessions **by name**?
Maybe use `fzf` on top of sessions list?

As the result I want to open sessions list via `CTRL-b` + `s` (how I can draw button here by the way?), write `rust` and sessions should be filtered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing the binding in your `.tmux.conf` to:

```
bind-key s split-window -v "tmux resize-pane -Z ';' \
 list-sessions -F '#S' | \
 fzf --reverse | xargs tmux switch-client -t"
```